# Gatsby : -bash: gatsby: command not found after npm install

Tags: npm, gatsby

When I try to install gatsby running `npm install gatsby-cli -g` , it does not work : when I run `gatsby --help`, it shows:

> bash:gatsby command not found

I have tried:

1. uninstalling and reinstalling NPM
2. this gitHub solution : https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/4967 
   I get a permission error when trying to change npm config set prefix /usr/local

I'm working on mac (version 10.14.5).
My environment details are as follows:
npm -v : 6.9.0
node -v : v10.16.0

What can I do to make it work?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you manage to successfully complete this tutorial? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-zero/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a permissions error, you could use `sudo npm install gatsby-cli -g` to run it as a superuser. I have to do this when I install something globally.

Comment: Thank's a lot it worked! I followed the github solution but did the `sudo npm install gatsby-cli -g`